# Android MVP взаимодействие presenter и adapter

Tags: java, android, mvp

Подскажите пожалуйста, более правильный вариант:

1. Presenter и адаптер содержат ссылку на List. Presenter добавляет, удаляет, изменяет items, сообщаяет item position во view, view просто обновляет адаптер. (notifySetDataChanges)
2. Только адптер содержит ссылку на List и сам добавляет, удаляет, изменяет items по команде от view. Presenter передает во view полноценный объект и команду что нужно сделать, добавить, удалить или изменить.

Или есть какие то другие классические варинты?

Answer (score 1):

Самое важно в этом вопросе является : используется ли в вашем проекте **Immutable objects**. Если нет, то изменение объекта в Presenter списке будет отображено и в списке Adapter. Если да, то необходимо всегда полностью заменять объекты при их изменении.

Второй вариант удобно использовать в паре с SortedList и DiffUtil. Эти классы упрощают работу со списком в RecyclerView. DiffUtil позволяет чётко определить изменения в списке, и уведомить именно об этих изменениях. 
На основе этого решения Presenter говорит View:

```
deleteElement(Element e);
insertNewElement(Element e);
updateElement(Element e);
insertNewElements(List<Element> elements) // Используй DiffUtil для этого случая
```

Получается, что в Adapter и Presenter будут иметь разные ссылки на коллекции, но одни ссылки на объекты этих коллекция. Вся логика определения изменения исходного списка ложиться на Presenter. Он должен определить изменения и сообщить View об этом:

```
deleteElement(int position);
updateElement(int position);
insertNewElements(List<Element> elements, int position);
insertNewElement(Element e, int position);
```